# Why does this requests/beautifulsoup code does not follow the URL loop?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm having some troubles concerning this code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for idPkmn in range(2,494,1):

    url = 'https://pokedex.org/#/pokemon/'+str(idPkmn)
    #print(url)

    webPage = requests.get(url)
    print(webPage)
    html = BeautifulSoup(webPage.content,'html.parser')

    namePkmn = html.find('h1',attrs={'class':'detail-panel-header'}).text.lower() # Get name
    print(namePkmn)
```

I am trying to take all Pokemon's names from this website, and if I run this code before :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://pokedex.org/#/pokemon/1'
webPage = requests.get(url)
htmlCode = BeautifulSoup(webPage.content,'html.parser')
namePkmn = htmlCode.find('h1',attrs={'class':'detail-panel-header'}).text.lower()
print(namePkmn)
```

It sends me back 'bulbasaur' (which is indeed the first Pokemon). However if I run the for loop, it seems that it effectively takes the good URL, but it keeps sending back 'bulbasaur' as the name which is wrong, as if my loop is sticked to the first page. I have checked on several pages and they all have the same structure where the name is effectively wrapped into a h1 title where the class is 'detail-panel-header'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `detail-panel-header` have the same value of `Bulbasaur` for all the pages and therefore you get the same value.

If you just want the names of all the Pokemon, then you can use the `ul` defined by the tag `monsters-list` and get all the Pokemon names as:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://pokedex.org/#/pokemon/0'
print(url)

webPage = requests.get(url)
print(webPage)
html = BeautifulSoup(webPage.content,'html.parser')

uls = html.find('ul', attrs = {'id':'monsters-list'})
for li in uls.findAll('li'):
    for span in li.findAll('span'):            
        print(span.text.lower())
```

Output:

```
bulbasaur
ivysaur
venusaur
charmander
charmeleon
charizard
squirtle
wartortle
blastoise
caterpie
metapod
butterfree
weedle
kakuna
beedrill
pidgey
pidgeotto
pidgeot
rattata
raticate
spearow
fearow
ekans
arbok
pikachu
raichu
sandshrew
sandslash
nidoran ♀
nidorina
nidoqueen
nidoran ♂
nidorino
nidoking
clefairy
clefable
vulpix
ninetales
jigglypuff
wigglytuff
zubat
golbat
oddish
gloom
vileplume
paras
parasect
venonat
venomoth
diglett
dugtrio
meowth
persian
psyduck
golduck
mankey
primeape
growlithe
arcanine
poliwag
poliwhirl
poliwrath
abra
kadabra
alakazam
machop
machoke
machamp
bellsprout
weepinbell
victreebel
tentacool
tentacruel
geodude
graveler
golem
ponyta
rapidash
slowpoke
slowbro
magnemite
magneton
farfetch'd
doduo
dodrio
seel
dewgong
grimer
muk
shellder
cloyster
gastly
haunter
gengar
onix
drowzee
hypno
krabby
kingler
voltorb
```